# Css para header transparente en moviles pero sigue saliendo el color blanco

Tags: css

Intento poner el header para moviles transparente pero sigue saliendo blanco.

El caso es que la transparencia funciona porque si pruebo en negro bajando 0.1 veo como funciona pero es como si algo mantiene al blanco de fondo en la cabecera movil

También he probado de dar margin y padding a los elementos de la cabecera y amplia los espacios pero también el bloque blanco

en el header formato ordenador si funciona transparente.

He probado con rgba con transparent y otras formas sin éxito

Si alguien pudiera arrojarme algo de luz..

gracias de antemano

```
   element.style {
}
.header-mobile {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-family: "Cera Pro Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #636363;
    background: transparent;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
user agent stylesheet
html {
    color: -internal-root-color;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1b251f;
}
```

Comment: Haz intentado probando con `background: transparent !important;`, espero te sirva

Comment: @José gracias por tu respuesta lamentablemente no me funciona. La cosa es que tal y como está veo que la transparencia funciona pero algo prevalece sobre este css y sigue apareciendo en blanco